# Cannot open Decision Center IBM ODM

Tags: redirect, center

I can open the Websphere console and Teamserver console properly. But, while I can open the   decision center console at first, I cannot open decision center after a while. I get a 'too many redirects' error when I try to open it. The browser gives me the error message 'this web page has a redirect loop '

How can I solve it? I updated teamserver from the Websphere console. But nothing changed, I stil cannot open it.

Answer (score 0):

If the Decision Center Enterprise console (aka teamserver) opens ok but the Decision Center Business Console does not then is sounds like a browser issue. In the later versions of ODM support for IE8 was dropped so you need to upgrade to a supported version of IE, Chrome or Firefox